# how to find successive elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm implementing a search in js and the core idea is that i've got an array of words to search from, let it be

```
const arr = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone']
```

and i've got a search input value (can be one or 2 words, or more), let it be

```
const string = 'i cant swim'
```

this input will not give me any result, because actually we don't have these 3 words in succession in the array. But if we take

```
const string = 'i cant'
```

it should return `['i', 'cant']` as 2 successive words in the search-array. How can i implement it?
My try is below:

```
    const search = []
    const searchStringArr = string.split(' ')       // ['i', 'cant']
    searchStringArr.forEach(str => {
     search.push(arr.filter(word => word.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())))
    })
```

But it returns the array of all words found, not taking into account their succession in the search array. Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive approach. Do you also need to match ['can't' 'swim'] if the arr contained those two? (i.e. not only matching from the start of the string)?

Here's a solution:

```js
function findConsecutiveMatches(string, arr){
  const searchStringArr = string.split(' ');    // ['i', 'cant', 'swim']
  let search = [];

  arr.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (searchStringArr[0].toLowerCase() != arr[idx].toLowerCase()){
      return;
    }
    search.push(el);
    if (idx == arr.length -1){
      return;
    }
    for (let diff = 1; diff <= Math.min(arr.length - idx + 1, searchStringArr.length -1); diff++){
      if (searchStringArr[diff].toLowerCase() != arr[idx + diff].toLowerCase()){
        return;
      }
      search.push(arr[idx + diff]);
    }
  });
  
  if (search.length != searchStringArr.length){
    search = [];
  }
  
  console.log(search);  
  return search;
}

const arr0 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string0 = "I cant";
findConsecutiveMatches(string0, arr0);
// output: ['i', 'cant'];

const arr1 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string1 = "I cant swim";
findConsecutiveMatches(string1, arr1);
// output: [];

const arr2 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string2 = "solve this";
findConsecutiveMatches(string2, arr2);
// output: ['solve', 'this'];

const arr3 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string3 = "solve this question";
findConsecutiveMatches(string3, arr3);
// output: [];

const arr4 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string4 = "I solve this";
findConsecutiveMatches(string4, arr4);
// output: [];
```

Examples with outputs:

```js
const arr0 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string0 = "I cant";
findConsecutiveMatches(string0, arr0);
// output: ['i', 'cant'];

const arr1 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string1 = "I cant swim";
findConsecutiveMatches(string1, arr1);
// output: [];

const arr2 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string2 = "solve this";
findConsecutiveMatches(string2, arr2);
// output: ['solve', 'this'];

const arr3 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string3 = "solve this question";
findConsecutiveMatches(string3, arr3);
// output: [];

const arr4 = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];
const string4 = "I solve this";
findConsecutiveMatches(string4, arr4);
// output: [];
```

Comment: You see, maybe i explained it poorly, cuz english is not my native, but if i search for `I solve` - it needs to return empty array, because they are not one after another in search-arr. If i search `solve this` - it should return ['solve', 'this'], because they fulfil the condition. If search for `solve, this, question` - returns empty array, cuz in the search array we don't have this phrase in succession, we have `solve, this, problem` instead... Hope i explained better....

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look through [useful methods for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const search = []
    const searchStringArr = string.split(' ')       // ['i', 'cant']
    searchStringArr.forEach(str => {
     if (arr.some(item => item.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase())) search.push(str)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns an array of all found words all the times. I need to return the found words only if they are in succession (one after another) in the search-array. And if not - return an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You should split your search string into an array( based on space seperator) and then compare all words with your array.

```js
const arr = ['i', 'cant', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'alone'];

const search = 'i cant swim';

var wordsArray = search.split(" ");

var result = [];

wordsArray.forEach( searchWord => {
  if(arr.includes(searchWord)) {
    result.push(searchWord);
  }
});

console.log( result );
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns an array of all found words all the times. I need to return the found words only if they are in succession (one after another) in the search-array. And if not - return an empty array